# Entendimento do algoritmo de CrossWord Puzzle

Tags: c#

Tenho esse algoritmo abaixo, queria saber se fiz um entendimento correto, se está muito superficial e sendo assim tem algo mais a acrescentar.

O meu entendimento do algoritmo está sendo explicitado nos comentários.

```
 static char[][] crossword;
    static string[] words;
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        crossword = new char[10][];
        for (int crossword_i = 0; crossword_i < 10; crossword_i++)
        {
            crossword[crossword_i] = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
        }
        words = Console.ReadLine().Split(';');

        fill(0);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", crossword.Select(x => new string(x))));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static bool fill(int p)
    {
        if (p == words.Length)
        {
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                //se o caracter lido for == "+" ele continua
                if (crossword[i][j] == '+')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //vai procurar a correspondencia da palavra 
                else if (findVerdical(i, j, p) || findHorizontal(i, j, p))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    //corresponde ao preenchimento das posições da matriz em vertial
    static bool findVerdical(int x, int y, int p)
    {

        //verifica se a subtração de 10 com o valor y for menor do que o tamanho da palavra  
        //se a condição for verdadeira. vai retornar false para poder preencher de forma horizontal
        if (10 - y < words[p].Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //percorre todas as palavras
        for (int i = y; i < y + words[p].Length; i++)
        {
            //verifica a correspondncia da letra com o "-"
            if (crossword[x][i] != '-' && crossword[x][i] != words[p][i - y])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //crio um temporario - será usado para fazer a troca do "-" pela letra correspondente
        var tmp = new char[10];
        for (int i = y; i < y + words[p].Length; i++)
        {
            tmp[i - y] = crossword[x][i];
            crossword[x][i] = words[p][i - y];
        }


        if (fill(p + 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        //o temporário foi preenchido com sucesso, agora vou reescrever minha matriz com a letra correspondente
        for (int i = y; i < y + words[p].Length; i++)
        {
            crossword[x][i] = tmp[i - y];
        }
        return false;
    }

    //corresponde ao preenchimento das posições da matriz em horizontal
    static bool findHorizontal(int x, int y, int p)
    {

        //
        if (10 - x < words[p].Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = x; i < x + words[p].Length; i++)
        {
            if (crossword[i][y] != '-' && crossword[i][y] != words[p][i - x])
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        var tmp = new char[10];
        for (int i = x; i < x + words[p].Length; i++)
        {
            tmp[i - x] = crossword[i][y];
            crossword[i][y] = words[p][i - x];
        }

        if (fill(p + 1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = x; i < x + words[p].Length; i++)
        {
            crossword[i][y] = tmp[i - x];
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: e os comentários do método `findHorizontal()`?

Comment: faz basicamente a mesma coisa que o "findVertical" porém para uma outra direção, a ideia é a mesma

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Se eu deixei passar algo importante desse código

Comment: Na minha opinião, se você quer saber se dominou um algoritmo é fazer a sua própria implementação do zero sem copiar nenhum código.